# How to enable Pulseaudio for Wine on Fedora 29?

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, alsa, wine

I have struggled to find an answer to this, so I wanted to share what I came up with. In my 32-bit wine prefix on Fedora 29, I have been unable to enable audio. I installed the `wine-pulseaudio` and `wine-alsa` packages, yet in `winecfg` no audio driver appears. Additionally, in `winetricks` the settings menu shows no sound settings at all! Why is this, and how do I enable audio?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that a 32-bit wine prefix will require the 32-bit version of the drivers. By default, on a 64-bit system, `dnf install wine-pulseaudio` will install the `wine-pulseaudio.x86_64` package. To enable audio in wine I succeeded only after running `dnf install wine-pulseaudio.i686`. After that, everything went smoothly. Obvious in hindsight, but I thought I'd share in case anybody else runs into the same issue.